# Changing IP of remote server with Powershell gives disconnection error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remotely invoke a command on a server and change it's IP, amongst other settings. I got the following line of code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $currentIP {`
$wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "ipenabled = 'true'";`
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers);`
$wmi.SetGateways($Defaultgateway);`
$wmi.EnableStatic($newIP,"255.255.255.0")} -Credential $cred
```

Every setting is applied but at the end of the script it starts going:

> The network connection to ###.##.###.## has been interrupted. Attempting to reconnect for up to 4 minutes...

And continues to fail the connection, obviously because the IP has changed. But am I issuing no more commands after the IP is changed. So why does this occur and how can I stop it?

Comment: well, the IP HAS CHANGED. what do you expect???

Comment: Since the IP change happens at the last command issued to the remote server. After changing the IP I would expect it to close the connection. Not interrupt it.

Comment: how would Powershell know that? it won't work like that. the connection would drop, because Powershell would not expect the IP to change.

Comment: is there anyway I can suppress the attempts of reconnecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behaviour as WinRM has no idea that the IP is being changed and during the `ScriptBlock` execution the IP changes which results in connection interrupted

For smoother connection closing, you can run `Invoke-Command` using `-AsJob` parameter so that it won't be interrupted eg:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName 192.168.56.103 -Credential administrator -AsJob -ScriptBlock {$wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "ipenabled = 'true'";$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("8.8.8.8");$wmi.SetGateways("1.1.1.1");$wmi.EnableStatic("192.168.56.104","255.255.255.0")}
```